# Difference between two promise functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise, arrow-functions

So with Vue and Nuxt to import a route lazily you can do

```
() => import('~/layouts/Container.vue').then(m => m.default || m)
```

But I don't want to type `.then(m => m.default || m)` each time I add a route. So I created a function that would do this called routeImport. Route import is really simple. It looks like this:

```
const routeImport = file => import(file).then(m => m.default || m)
```

So now I can add my route like

```
() => routeImport('~/layouts/Container.vue')
```

But this does not give the same result. The first function returns a component whilst the other one throws the error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '~/layouts/Container.vue'
```

Does anybody know how I can replace this function?

Comment: _"The first function returns a component whilst the other does not."_ What does the other one return?

Comment: The other one returns nothing. It seems like it does not come in `then` even though it should

Comment: Try appending `.catch(e => console.log(e))` and watch your console, maybe it's related to relative paths (e.g. if you use `./path/file` or even just `path/file`)?

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: Are you using webpack?

Comment: Not directly. I am using vue and nuxt which in turn are using webpack

Comment: That's probably the problem. Webpack is really picky about what it bundles. Webpack can detect `import("somefile")` and include `somefile` in your bundle, but if you import a variable then webpack won't know what the variable's value is and will exclude the file from your bundle.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49121053/how-to-use-a-webpack-dynamic-import-with-a-variable-query-string

Comment: Interesting. How can you fix this. My knowledge about webpcak is to little to be able to know what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like the issue is that you are using a fully dynamic variable as the query string for your `import()` function, which [webpack cannot statically analyze](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#dynamic-expressions-in-import), so it isn't including the desired module in your bundle.

You might want to consider giving webpack a *hint* as to what you are loading. For example:

```
const layoutImport = layout => import(`~/layouts/${layout}.vue`).then(m => m.default || m)
```

Or:

```
const routeImport = file =>
  import(
    /* webpackInclude: /layouts/(Container|OtherView|Etc).vue$/ */
    file
  ).then(m => m.default || m)
```

This will cause webpack to include all layouts in your bundle (or the specific layouts included in your regex) but still allow you dynamically import them. Note that `import()` is treated as a split point, so while the files are included in your bundle, they'll typically be grouped into a separate "chunk".

You can control some aspects of the chunk (such as its name) with [magic comments](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#magic-comments). If you want to group layouts into different chunks, then you may need more than one import function:

```
const groupAImport = file =>
  import(
    /* webpackInclude: /layouts/(Container1|Container2).vue$/ */
    file
  ).then(m => m.default || m)

const groupBImport = file =>
  import(
    /* webpackInclude: /layouts/(Container1|Container3|Etc).vue$/ */
    file
  ).then(m => m.default || m)
```