# How can I modify a lazy loaded Webpack module path?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

I have a Vue app which uses Webpack and dynamic imports:

```
// App.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="isBtnClicked = true">Load lazy component</button>
    <LazyComponent v-if="isBtnClicked" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    LazyComponent: () => import('./components/LazyComponent'),
  },
  data: () => {
    return {
      isBtnClicked: false,
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

```
// components/LazyComponent.vue
<template>
    <p>Hello from lazy component</p>
</template>
```

When the button in the app is clicked, the Webpack runtime dynamically creates a `<script>` tag and appends it to the `head` of the document.

Is there a way to modify the `src` attribute of this generated `<script>` tag? I would like to add a dynamic query parameter to it appends the element to the DOM.

The currently generated tag looks something like:

```
<script charset="utf-8" src="/js/0.js"></script>
```

And I would like it to look like:

```
<script charset="utf-8" src="/js/0.js?mytoken=12345"></script>
```

where `mytoken` and `12345` are generated at runtime.

I am using webpack 4.44.0, vue 2.6.11, and vue-loader 15.9.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49121053/how-to-use-a-webpack-dynamic-import-with-a-variable-query-string) and [this](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2992) it doesn't look like you can do this in webpack 4. I'm not entirely sure, but it looks like [this pull request](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/pull/8462) may allow it to be done in webpack 5.